# What were Kant's thoughts on ethics and "Transcendental Deduction"?

Tags: ethics, kant, deduction

What is Kant's thoughts on ethics? And what do his "Transcendental Deduction" ideas have to do with his ideas on ethics?

Please keep in mind that I'm a a newb to philosophy, so the simper and more easily digestible your answer is, the better for me.

**UPDATE:**
I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwOCmJevigw) which helped me understand a lot. Anyone know where I can find a similar 3 min introduction to Transcendental Deduction?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a decent introduction [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-moral/).

Is there any particular reason why you didn't do a quick search in the basic encyclopedias first?  Imagine what would happen if everyone behaved that way...

Comment: I found that page too. It seemed really dense. Guess I'm missing some of the basic precepts to understand. I'll try to make it through that and update my question. The last part of your answer presents me with an ethical dilemma. +1